# I want to simplify the code? Is there a way?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a nested if else loop, which checks if the user is entering the date correctly on the userform textbox. (Date format and within the listed start and end dates.)

```
    Private Sub Setbutton_Click()
    If Not IsDate(txtbox.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Input is not in date format." & Chr(13) & "Enter PROJECT START date in date format." & Chr(13) & "(dd/mm/yyyy)", vbCritical
        Cancel = True
    Else
        If CDate(txtbox.Value) < ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G4").Value Then
            MsgBox "PROJECT START date is before SCHEDULE START date" & Chr(13) & "Enter a date after" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G4") & " or press Cancel and modify the SCHEDULE START date.", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If CDate(txtbox.Value) > ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G5").Value Then
                MsgBox "PROJECT START date is after SCHEDULE END date" & Chr(13) & "Enter a date before" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G5") & " or press Cancel and modify the SCHEDULE END date.", vbCritical
                Cancel = True
            Else
            (If all okay run the Main code)
            End If
      End If
End If
```

Is there any way/trick to simplify this check and nested if loops?
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps Code review would be better as this is working.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to Stack Overflow. Is there something I needed to do?

Comment: Well, checking what each Stack is for will help. See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike I will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `ElseIf`?:

```vb
Private Sub Setbutton_Click()
    If Not IsDate(txtbox.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Input is not in date format." & Chr(13) & "Enter PROJECT START date in date format." & Chr(13) & "(dd/mm/yyyy)", vbCritical
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf CDate(txtbox.Value) < ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G4").Value Then
        MsgBox "PROJECT START date is before SCHEDULE START date" & Chr(13) & "Enter a date after" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G4") & " or press Cancel and modify the SCHEDULE START date.", vbCritical
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf CDate(txtbox.Value) > ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G5").Value Then
        MsgBox "PROJECT START date is after SCHEDULE END date" & Chr(13) & "Enter a date before" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G5") & " or press Cancel and modify the SCHEDULE END date.", vbCritical
        Cancel = True
    Else
        ' (If all okay run the Main code)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

**Improve Code Readability (Simplify!?)**

```vb
Private Sub Setbutton_Click()

    Cancel = True

    If IsDate(txtbox.Value) Then ' is a date
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home")
            If CDate(txtbox.Value) < .Range("G4").Value Then ' less than
                MsgBox "PROJECT START date is before SCHEDULE START date" _
                    & vbLf & "Enter a date after" & " " & .Range("G4") _
                    & " or press Cancel and modify the SCHEDULE START date.", _
                    vbCritical
            ElseIf CDate(txtbox.Value) > .Range("G5").Value Then ' greater than
                MsgBox "PROJECT START date is after SCHEDULE END date" _
                    & vbLf & "Enter a date before" & " " & .Range("G5") _
                    & " or press Cancel and modify the SCHEDULE END date.", _
                    vbCritical
            Else
                Cancel = False
            End If
        End With
    Else ' is no date
        MsgBox "Input is not in date format." & vbLf _
            & "Enter PROJECT START date in date format." & vbLf _
            & "(dd/mm/yyyy)", vbCritical
    End If
    
    If Cancel Then Exit Sub
    
    ' The input is valid. Continue with the main code.
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "early exit" approach to avoid nesting `if` blocks.  The idea is to perform one check at a time (very similar to what you're already doing to be honest), and exit the `Sub` if a check ever fails.  Notice how the max indentation here is one level:

(This code is untested.)

```
Private Sub ExitEarlyExample()

    ' Is it a date?
    If Not IsDate(txtbox.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Input is not in date format." & Chr(13) & "Enter PROJECT START date in date format." & Chr(13) & "(dd/mm/yyyy)", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If the code reaches here, it's a date.
    
    ' Is it a valid date?
    If CDate(txtbox.Value) < ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G4").Value Then
        MsgBox "PROJECT START date is before SCHEDULE START date" & Chr(13) & "Enter a date after" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G4") & " or press Cancel and modify the SCHEDULE START date.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If the code reaches here, the  date is after the schedule start date.
    
    ' Is it a valid date?
    If CDate(txtbox.Value) > ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G5").Value Then
        MsgBox "PROJECT START date is after SCHEDULE END date" & Chr(13) & "Enter a date before" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G5") & " or press Cancel and modify the SCHEDULE END date.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If the code reaches here, the date is before the schedule end date.
    
    ' Run the rest of your code here.
    
End Sub
```